# envoyproxy validate "Auth-Sub-Identities"?

Tags: envoyproxy

We are exploring between nginx with js and envoy proxy, checking if  there is instruction for envoy proxy to parse `Auth-Sub-Identities` in the headers and validate if the matching string is found ?